# $(5x +1) ÷ (3x)$ is not a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, fractions

On the [Mathwarehouse page on polynomial equations](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/polynomial/polynomial-equation.php), it gives this expression as an **antiexample, something that is not a polynomial**:
$(5x +1) ÷ (3x)$

However, it also says on the same page that **if it is possible to simplify** an expression using addition, subtraction or multiplication, then it *is* a polynomial.

Following that logic, it would seem to me that their anti-example **is actually a polynomial**, as it seems that it can be rewritten as:
$(5x + 1)(\frac 13 x)$

So which is correct? Is it or is it not a polynomial?

Comment: Addition, subtraction and multiplication. **Not** division. $1/3x$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: $\frac{1}{3x}$ is not a polynomial; multiplying a polynomial by something that isn't may mean the product is no longer a polynomial.

Comment: @Clayton thanks, I fixed my formatting - I didn't mean for it to read as x as part of the deonominator

Comment: The reciprocal of $3x$ is not $\frac13 x$.

Answer (score 2):

> Definition: $f(x)$ is a real polynomial if it can be written on the form $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_n x^n$ where $n$ is an integer and $a_k$ are real numbers.

From this definition it is not hard to prove the following:

> If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials then $af(x)+bg(x)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)g(x)$ are also polynomials

However polynomials are not closed under division. Dividing two polynomials can give a polynomial, but it does not have to and your example is not a polynomial.

One way to prove this is to assume that $\frac{5x+1}{3x}$ is a polynomial and try to derive a contradiction. By the definition above we can write $\frac{5x+1}{3x} = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots +a_n x^n$.  By considering the growth of the two sides of the equation as $x\to \infty$ we conclude that we must have $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n=0$. This leaves us with $\frac{5x+1}{3x} = a_0$ a constant. This is absurd and it follows that $\frac{5x+1}{3x}$ cannot be a polynomial.

Comment: The moment you said to consider $x\to\infty$, I thought that was a wonderful idea... except it is nowhere within the means of algebra to define.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a polynomial. Your simplification does not work: the first expression is
$$ \frac{5x+1}{3x}. $$
Your second expression has $x$ and $1/x$ mixed up, basically.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a polynomial.

A polynomial can NOT include a variable with negative power.

Comment: I'm not sure this reply addresses the OP's Question.  Careful reading will show you the concern is about cases where some expressions can be rewritten to avoid the inclusion of "a variable with negative power".  E.g. $(5x + x^2) ÷ (3x)$ could be rewritten as a polynomial.